# Packing $n$-diamonds in a $n$-cube and a number theoretic conjecture?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, packing-problem

### Background

Recently I was doing some recreational mathematics and stumbled across an interesting observation:

What is the maximum number of diamonds (square rotated at $45^o$) can one fit into an $n \times n$ square, where the area of the diamond  is $2$? The picture below illustrates a square of $n=3$ and fits $1$ diamond
[image]

It shouldn't be hard to convince yourself that this is related to the question of how many numbers are there divisible by $2$  less than $n^2$. Why? Consider labelling each grid point with a number:

[image]

A diamond is formed whenever one joins the factors of $2$ together! Of course,this is only true when $n$ is an odd number $n>1$.
(Also imagine you have the number of diamonds you can fit then with Euler's characteristic formula you can find the number of vertices)

Now, we can extend this for a diamonds in a $5 \times 5$ square:

[image]

Similarly  for a cube we can imagine divide it into smaller cubes and labelling them: $1,2,3,4,\dots$ and join the mid-point of every $2$'nd brick and get a pyramid. which happens to be maximum packing efficiency of the pyramids in a cube.

[image]

### Conjecture

"The packing efficiency always is maximum for a shape created by joining the mid-point vertices in a $n$-dimensional diamond (square for $2$, pyramid for $3$, $4 =$  ?)"

### Question

Is there a general formula for the shape (note in the pyramid the tip is the centre of the cube rather than the midpoint of the edge)?
Is the conjecture true or false?

Comment: The generalization of a diamond is generally considered to be the dual of a cube, that is, the [cross-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope) (an [octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron#Dual) in 3d). But I don't know about the negative space when the octahedron is inscribed in a cube, whether it can be decomposed into pieces that form more octahedra.

Comment: Your "diamond" is the figure formed by joining the midpoints of the edges of a square. The three dimensional analog is probably the octahedron, inscribed in a cube by joining the midpoints of the faces. That might get you started.

Comment: Reason for downvote?